# Why is .mxml the default file filter in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, intellij-15

When finding in path, the default is .mxml for file masks. This doesn't make sense from an alphabetical point, or being a frequently used file type for an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an implementation accident; there is no other reason for this.